# flutter apps not getting data immediately from shared preferences at first launch

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

i have a field called `highScore` it's data is persisted in shared preferences, and i want to retrvie it's data and show in `first_page` that get displayed when the app first start, but at first start it just says null and i have to go to `quiz_page` and come back to get the data even though i tried loading the data from `initState()`.

`question_bank`

```
    class QuestionBank {
  static final QuestionBank _questionBank = QuestionBank._internal();

  factory QuestionBank() {
    return _questionBank;
  }

  QuestionBank._internal();

  int _questionNumber = 0;
  int _score = 0;
  int highScore;

  incrementCounter() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    highScore = (prefs.getInt('counter') ?? 0) + 1;
    prefs.setInt('counter', highScore);
  }

  loadCounter() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    highScore = (prefs.getInt('counter') ?? 0);
  }
  int getScore() => _score;

  int getLength() => _questionList.length;
}
```

`first_page`

```
    class FirstPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FirstPageState createState() => _FirstPageState();
}

class _FirstPageState extends State<FirstPage> {
  QuestionBank questionBank;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    questionBank = QuestionBank();
    questionBank.loadCounter();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white24,
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'High Score: ${questionBank.highScore}',
                style: titleStyle,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 76,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
                child: Image(
                  image: AssetImage(
                    'images/logoDesigne7crop.png',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 30,
              ),
              Container(
                height: 70,
                width: double.infinity,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: ChoiceButton(
                    btnText: 'start the quiz',
                    tap: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(startQuizRoute);
                    }),
              ),
              Container(
                  height: 70,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: ChoiceButton(
                      btnText: 'search',
                      tap: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(searchRoute);
                      })),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`quiz_page`

```
   class QuizPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _QuizPageState createState() => _QuizPageState();
}

class _QuizPageState extends State<QuizPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  QuestionBank questionBank = QuestionBank();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 14, right: 8, left: 6),
              child: TopRow(questionBank: questionBank),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 40),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Center(
                    child: Text(questionBank.getQuestionTitle(),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: titleStyle),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, bottom: 20),
                    child: Image.asset(
                      questionBank.getQuestionImage(),
                      height: 180,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 76,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 12.0, vertical: 5),
                      child: ChoiceButton(
                        btnText: 'Fruit',
                        tap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            questionBank.bigCheck(1);
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 76,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 12.0, vertical: 5),
                      child: ChoiceButton(
                        btnText: 'Vegetable',
                        tap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            questionBank.bigCheck(2);
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 76,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 12.0, vertical: 5),
                      child: ChoiceButton(
                        btnText: 'Fungus',
                        tap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            questionBank.bigCheck(3);
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 76,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 12.0, vertical: 5),
                      child: ChoiceButton(
                        btnText: 'Berry',
                        tap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            questionBank.bigCheck(4);
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TopRow extends StatelessWidget {
  const TopRow({
    Key key,
    @required this.questionBank,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final QuestionBank questionBank;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          'High Score: ${questionBank.highScore}',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: Colors.white),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ),
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Score: ${questionBank.getScore()}',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: Colors.white),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 220,
            ),
            Icon(
              FontAwesome.heart,
              size: 26,
            ),
            Icon(
              Icons.audiotrack,
              size: 26,
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: check `FutureBuilder` class documentation

Comment: thanks, but i don't want another widget to be shown while loading the data, i want the data to be shown immediately.

Comment: *" i want the data to be shown immediately"*, you cannot do that - if your function returns `Future` you cannot get it "right now" - simply use `FutureBuilder` - the official docs have some basic [example code](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html#widgets.FutureBuilder.1)

Comment: but can't i cache that data somewhere so it be available next time i launch the app?

Comment: sure you can (in [File](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/File-class.html) for example), but why would you want to use "shared preferences" then?

Comment: so does that mean shared preferences always must be asynchronous?

Comment: yes - they are always async

Comment: oh i have to find another way, thanks anyway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207657/discussion-between-hiwa-jalal-and-pskink).

Answer (score 0):

`questionBank.loadCounter();` is a sync task meaning it will take time and thread will passover this point.

now you have option like wait and show something until it gets loaded

for that you can use `FutureBuilder`  with `future: questionBank.loadCounter()`

Read at https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

As per discussions in comment create a class

```
class AppConstant {
  static QuestionBank questionBank=QuestionBank();
}
```

Now before calling run call loadCounter

```
void main() {
  await AppConstant.questionBank.loadCounter();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Now instead of initializing question bank in state. directly use `AppConstant.questionBank`

Comment: but i want to show the value the second the app runs and not display another widget, is there a way to do this like caching it or something like that?

Comment: Store `QuestionBank questionBank;`  in a static class and then before runApp call `await questionBank.loadCounter();`

Comment: can you please explain more, i don't know much about asynchronous programming and for now i just want to finish this app.

Comment: i did this but this made my app to not get started and freeze on a white screen!

Comment: Are there any errors? Better implement a splash screen where you will do this. Actually without understanding async things its going to be tough. Just remember that whenever you will access card, network or anything you will get async response  now its up-to you how you wanna adjust the time elapsed in the ui.

Comment: actually the first solution(using FutureBuilder) worked, i don't think the second one will be a good idea.